# What is the material this bathroom counter is made from?

Tags: materials, countertops

The photo below is my bathroom counter. (Sorry for the shadow and the light highlights, this is the best lighting I have, and some kind of wax got put on it recently.)

I can't quite tell what the material is. It is black, and it appears to have some transparent inclusions; there appear to be transparent spaces that cast shadows inside the counter (the very dark grains in the photo).

I have hard water, and the surface water stains very easy, if that helps.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there are a number of variations, but I guessing that it basically consists of bits of stone or plastic embedded in a sort of epoxy base.

Comment: man made solid surface - probably mostly epoxy resin.

Comment: Check out the shadow effects around the bright spot in the shadow! this photo may actually be accidentally really good.

Comment: Probably some sort of "solid surface" epoxy material, like HotLicks and FreshCodemonger suggest. Cabinet shops and countertop shops use it all the time. Difficult to deduce the manufacturer of the substance from the picture. Several companies provide it: Corian, Wilsonart, lots of others. You might be able to tell the manufacturer from possible ink stamp or printing under the countertop.

Comment: Yes to a synthetic, possibly quartz-based, but is there a reason other than curiosity that you want to know? If it’s the hard water issue, that’ll be true for any dark polished surface.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you _really_ after?

Comment: @FreeMan Perceptive. The things I'm really after are: how do I clean the (very large, very hard to get off) hard water stains from this material? I had some professional cleaners come and they put some kind of wax on it that didn't seem to stick, is there a special wax I should/could be using for this material?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate see above

Comment: So then, why don't you ask, "How do I clean the hard water stains off of this counter top made of an unknown material?" _THAT_ is what you really want to know. Knowing what it's made of is probably nice, but it's not what you're really after.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm interested in knowing both things. I thought I'd ask this first, do my own research, and then if I still didn't know how to clean it off, ask specifically how to clean it off. I am actually interested in knowing what the material is, independent of how to clean it off. In my experience, when I ask two questions in one post, only one gets answered, so I was trying to separate my questions. And I have to ask, why are you spending time criticizing how I'm asking my questions instead of helping to answer one of them?

Comment: Well...  A) you haven't provided enough info here for someone to be able to answer your question after 4 days, B) we like people to ask the question for which they want an answer, not theoretical ones (those are off-topic), C) It's been my experience that a lot of people come up with a solution but don't know how to execute it, then ask about that, but that their solution wasn't a particularly good one in the first place, D) I don't have a clue what the answer is, but I'm trying to help you refine the question so someone who might may be able to help you.